# How does this prove that the objective function in K-means clustering never increases?

Tags: clustering, optimization, k-means

I am reading the ISLR textbook (pg. 518-519, 12.4) and having trouble understanding why K-means clustering never increases. I can understand it conceptually but I don't understand the mathematical justification for it. For example, the objective function for K-means clustering is:

$$
\operatorname{minimize}_{C_{1},...,C_{K}}{\left\{\sum_{k=1}^{K}\frac{1}{\left| C_{k} \right|} \sum_{i,i'\epsilon C_{k}}^{}\sum_{j=1}^{p}\left ( x_{ij}-x_{i'j} \right )^2 \right\}}
$$

ISLR says the K-means clustering algorithm is guaranteed to decrease the value of the above equation at each step. It presents the following identity as why this is the case"

$$
\frac{1}{\left| C_{k} \right|} \sum_{i,i'\epsilon C_{k}}^{}\sum_{j=1}^{p}\left ( x_{ij}-x_{i'j} \right )^2 = 2 \sum_{i\epsilon C_{k}}^{}\sum_{j=1}^{p}\left ( x_{ij}-\bar{x}_{kj} \right )^2
$$

where:

$$
\bar{x}_{kj}=\frac{1}{\left| C_{k} \right|}\sum_{i\epsilon C_{k}}x_{ij}
$$

I'm confused how the above shows that the objective function always decreases? Can someone explain in layman's terms

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).